# Density of primes with $x^2 \equiv17\bmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to find the Dirichlet density of the set of primes such that $17$ is a square modulo $p$. I have that $$\text{dens}(X)=8\cdot\phi(17)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}.$$ Where X is the set of primes described and $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. I understand all of it except where the $8$ comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By quadratic reciprocity, $17$ is a square modulo $p$ iff $p$ is a square
modulo $17$. Such $p$ comprise $8$ of the $16$ nonzero residue classes modulo $17$. By Dirichlet's theorem, the Dirichlet density of such $p$
is $8/16=1/2$.

Alternatively you could appeal to the Chebotarev Density Theorem for the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{17})$.

Comment: Thank you. Other than calculation, is there any way to find that such $p$ comprise $8$ of the $16$ non-zero residue classes?

Comment: @PercyF2519 Well, quadratic residues always fill up half the available space....

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I did know this... There are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ quadratic residues modulo $p$. D'oh!

Thanks for your help.